# Problems in windows application with error handling and textbox display

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I wrote out a very simple code. I am trying to get it to do two things for me

1. I want it to continually show the user inputs and what the output would be. Right now it does not. I think this is a problem with my appendtext
2. should I use a try and catch for error handling? That's if the user enters more than one decimal my code crashes. I would like to know how to make it where it reverts back to one decimal and continues on.

Here is a snippet of my code.

Also to note, only in my addition method did I start the appendtext, since it didn't work and I kept getting stuck I stopped and came here...

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.AppendText(".");
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    c = "+";
    num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.AppendText("+");
}

private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    c = "-";
    num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = "";
}

private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    c = "*";
    num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = "";
}

private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    c = "/";
    num1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = "";
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    num2 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    double result;
    if (c == "+") {
        result = num1 + num2;
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `AppendText` perhaps using concatenation would help you work out whats wrong. eg: `textBox1.Text +=`

Comment: I tried that one as well, and it gave me the same results when I press +, so I think its a change needed in the + method or the = method

Answer (score 0):

When you append "+", the num2 is equal to value1+"+"+value2 or something so try to use this code

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     double result;
     if (c == "+") {

        num2 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text.Split('+')[1]);//bad idea but will work
        result = num1 + num2;
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
 }
```

also try

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     double result;
     if (c == "+") {

     num2 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text.SubString(textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf('+')+1));
        result = num1 + num2;
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
 }
```

PS: try catch needed!